# How to append multiple column using Select based on condition in Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want to select the multiple column based on if condition, While adding "Select" method as nested it is not working, Getting null for each properties in the class. So how to fix this?

```
public async Task<Form?> GetFormByIdAsync(long formId, string organisationId,
    bool includeBuilderSchema = false,bool includeViewerSchema = false)
{
    var query = _dbContext.Forms.AsQueryable()
        .Where(f => f.Id.Equals(formId) && f.OrganizationId.Equals(organisationId)).Select(f =>
            new Form()
            {
                Id = f.Id,
                Name = f.Name,
                Description = f.Description,
            });

    if (includeBuilderSchema)
    {
        query = query.Select(f => new Form()
        {
            FormBuilderSchema = f.FormBuilderSchema,
        });
    }

    if (includeViewerSchema)
    {
        query = query.Select(f => new Form()
        {
            FormViewerSchema = f.FormViewerSchema,
        });
    }

    var result = await query
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You want to select columns based on condition? You should then project (Select) entity with needed columns inside if condition. There should not be default Select inside your query. Instead it should be moved inside if conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The second SELECT is overriding the first, only the FormBuilderSchema and OrganizationId props are initialized. Try:

```
public async Task<Form?> GetFormByIdAsync(long formId, string organisationId,
    bool includeBuilderSchema = false)
{
    var query = _dbContext.Forms.AsQueryable()
        .Where(f => f.Id.Equals(formId) && f.OrganizationId.Equals(organisationId));

    if (includeBuilderSchema)
    {
        query = query.Select(f => new Form()
        {
            Id = f.Id,
            Name = f.Name,
            Description = f.Description,
            FormBuilderSchema = f.FormBuilderSchema,
            OrganizationId = f.OrganizationId,
        });
    }
    else 
    {
        query = query.Select(f => new Form()
        {
            Id = f.Id,
            Name = f.Name,
            Description = f.Description,
        });
    }

    var result = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Bluetonic , I want to append to existing select based on conditions, I updated the given example, Can you help me with new example?

Answer (score 0):

I added condition using ternary operator while assigning fields inside Select function.

```
public async Task<Form?> GetFormByIdAsync(long formId, string organisationId,
    bool includeBuilderSchema = false,
    bool includeViewerSchema = false
    )
{
    var query = _dbContext.Forms
        .Where(f => f.Id.Equals(formId) && f.OrganizationId.Equals(organisationId)).Select(f =>
            new Form
            {
                Id = f.Id,
                Name = f.Name,
                FormBuilderSchema = includeBuilderSchema ? f.FormBuilderSchema : default,
                FormViewerSchema = includeViewerSchema ? f.FormViewerSchema : default,
            });

    var generatedQuery = query.ToQueryString();

    var result = await query
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();


    return result;
}
```

When `includeBuilderSchema` is true, the `generatedQuery` is changed correctly.

But not sure is it good coding practice.